# Query with dimension parameter as a metadata in Mapserver's client

Tags: wms, mapserver, wms-time

I've read the [documentation to use mapserver as a client](http://mapserver.org/fr/ogc/wms_client.html) but I can't see how to query a layer which get a dimension parameter using a metadata value.
The only way I found is to add the dimension parameter/value in the connection string this way :

```
CONNECTION      "http://host?DATE=2014-08-20&"
```

Can't it be done with metadata? Is it possible to add custom metadata that will be included in the url or mapserver only understand predefined ones?

Comment: You are cascading some external WMS through your MapServer and you want to pass the WMS-time parameters to the remote server? I fear that is not possible with standard WMS. MapServer does support variables but only in some parts of the mapfile http://mapserver.org/cgi/runsub.html#parameters-supported. I have read that people do more advanced things with mapscript but all I know about that is that such thing exists.